# how do I average multiple arrays in a for loop elementwise python

Tags: python, numpy

I know this might be a trivial question but I seem to be doing something wrong.  I am trying to load different data by adding each set of data (import_data_n) to the previous (import_data) and then take an average of the data before adding a new set to the currently determined average.

Below is a snipet of the script am using and for some reason the import_data_n ignores all the data sets before the last set of data.

```
n =2 
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(folder_dir + 'intial*.npy'))
filenames = filenames[0:3] 
import_data = np.load(filenames[0])
for f in range (1,n+1): 
    import_data_n = np.load (filenames[f])
    print (import_data_n)
    result_data = (np.array(import_data) + np.array(import_data_n))/2
```

I have used similar approach previously in matlab and it worked. To check if the import_data_n reads the files i want I have requested a print fo the files loaded each time.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint - `import_data` never changes in your code above, so your output is just `result_data = (np.array(np.load(filenames[0])) + np.array(np.load(filenames[n]))/2`.

I would also note that if you want to just average element-wise over `n` arrays, then taking repeated averages over subsequent summations is not the right calculation to do!

Comment: Thanks @spco for the point on the average but when I run the above snipet and print out the import_data_n, each other data set is printed but the averaged output is only of the first and last data set.

Comment: Thanks for your help found out that I was initialising my data with import_data and then discarding that in the subsequent line when determining the average.

Comment: Exactly - nowhere do you keep track of your running average, which I assumed was the role of `result_data`. If my reply was helpful, please upvote or select it as the best answer.